# Chamber of Commerce with multiple levels and sublevels of membership

Tags: civimember, evaluating-civicrm

I am in the process of evaluating CiviCRM for a Chamber of Commerce site that I am working on.

This specific Chamber has 4 levels of membership, each with 4 levels within it,  So:
Classic with 1 to 5 employees = $175
Classic with 6 to 10 employees = $225
Classic with 11 to 20 employees = $275
Classic with 21+ employees = $325

And then Bronze, Silver and Gold with the same divisions.

Can this be accomplished with CiviCRM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - this is fairly straightforward.  In fact, unless there are different benefits to membership, I'd only create a single membership type with different price set levels.  If there are different membership benefits, I'd consider multiple membership types.

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks.  I will push forward and get it going.