# restructuring membership programs for civicrm from altru

Tags: civimember

We use programs for our memberships. They are broken down like so:

```
Basic Membership Program
    Single (one named adult)
    Single Household (one named adult plus all children [children are always anonymous)
    Dual (two named adults)
    Dual Household (two named adults, plus all children)
Contributing Membership Program
   Pine Cone (everything from Dual HH plus some extras)
   Conifer (everything from Pine Cone plus some extras)
The Inner Circle
    Everything from the Conifer plus some extra extra goodies.
```

*The last membership listed is given as a perk for making a contribution of $5000 or more. The revenue is entered as contributions and not membership revenue in the GL.*

So, I am not seeing programs and levels and am wondering how to recreate this in CiviCRM.

Comment: Flagging my own question as it seems to be answered by this post.  http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/11137/chamber-of-commerce-with-multiple-levels-and-sublevels-of-membership